# How to access TFS Rest API using Basic Authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

I am using TFS 2020 and try accessing Rest API

```
http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/<Project>/_apis/build/builds?definitions=12345&$top=1&statusFilter=all&api-version=6.0
```

using basic authentication (username and password) but getting below error.

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic navjpidW5nYUAxZQ=='}
```

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

Comment: By default Azure DevOps disables basic auth when the server isn't configured on `https` for security reasons. Basic auth over http provides *very little* security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this by myself where I have used a dedicated account which has all the required permission to access the TFS API and I have used Python for this purpose.

**Sample Code:**

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import json

username = "naveen"
password = "test"
auth = HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password')

api_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0"
response = requests.get(url=api_url, auth=auth)

print(f"Output: {response.json()}")
```

*For reference: https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm*